# How can integrate html template in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, templates

I'm new to codeigniter. please tell me how can I integrate or install a html theme/template in codeigniter ? (my css folder path=news/css and application folder path=news/application where news is my main folder)

-thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very simple, very powerful way to do templates in codeigniter that is also very flexible.
http://news.dice.com/2013/02/18/how-to-build-a-to-do-app-with-codeigniter/

ignore the title, most of the lesson is about setting up templates in CI.

Note that i was first exposed to this method from a jeffrey way CI tutorial on net.tutsplus.com 
All of them are worth checking out: http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/codeigniter-from-scratch/

edit -- ok this is good enough addition to post. So in the tutorial, on the template.php page, you will see

```
 $this->load->view($maincontent);
```

which is cool. but this is much better:

```
// load your header views

 $templatefolder = 'beta/';

 if(isset($content01))
 $this->load->view($templatefolder.$content01);

 if(isset($content02))
 $this->load->view($templatefolder.$content02);

 if(isset($content03))
 $this->load->view($templatefolder.$content03);

 // load your footer views
```

so instead of calling the view "maincontent", i've put in references to $content1, $content2, etc. Because we are doing if isset none of them are required. that way you can easily send more then one view file to the template. Or none at all if you are just showing a message, etc. Also notice that we have $templatefolder - that way you can easily reuse the template file for other site templates, even with the same content.

in your controller (similar to tutorial) it would be

```
 $data['content01'] = 'codeigniterrawks';
 $data['content02'] = 'mypetlion';
 // beta template
 $this->load->view( 'template_beta', $data );
```

note how easy it is if i want to bring in those same view files into a different template

```
 $data['content01'] = 'codeigniterrawks';
 $data['content02'] = 'mypetlion';
 // alpha template
 $this->load->view( 'template_alpha', $data );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I understood your answer and thats similar with my thought.at first I thought the html template insyallation was likely magento or wordpress as I was much new to codeigniter. but by 2 days study I understood some thats likely your answer as have to set and load the html code part by part. so no special function or something else required. just have to arrange the parts and have to load by controller.

Comment: great! one tip, in the header view file that you include in your template, consider using the CI helper base_url() for your css and assets links, like: <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet"> That way your header file will work for different builds that have different urls. Same for links, consider using anchor() if appropriate.

Comment: the first link is not available now.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact question about a week ago, this guide really helped me:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/an-introduction-to-views-templating-in-codeigniter/

To do the CSS url's, I added "uri" to my libraries in config/autoload.php (so it looks like this:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('uri', 'database');)
```

" type="text/css" media="screen" />

the base_url function automatically return whatever the base url of your site is, ie

```
http://localhost/news/
```

with the argument appended to the end.

The reason behind this is that if/when you ever need to migrate servers, you just change the base_url in the config file and it automatically updates across all of your templates and sources.

Comment: let me try that link. and my autoload file contains $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session'); already. so if I use uri,database then wouldn't that cause harm of session purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I'm using this and it's very powerful.

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template