# Creating custom templates for rendering common pages

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, header, footer

I am new to codeigniter, I would like to know how I can use custom templates for rendering common pages like header, footer, sidepanel,etc. along with data to the pages.

```
class Template {

function show($view)
{
    <?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>
    <?php $this->load->view($view,$data); ?>
    <?php $this->load->view('footer',$data); ?>
}
}
```

here is the sample what i meant for . can any one help please.

Comment: I promise this will rock your world like sweet victory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968868/how-can-integrate-html-template-in-codeigniter/14971423#14971423 Flexible? yes. Powerful? yes. Simple simple yet still powerfully flexible? yes.

Answer (score 2):

Do not call 3 views in one controller function because they will limit you. instead call only one view which calls 3 other view.

this is your plan:

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view($view,$data);
$this->load->view('footer',$data);
```

the problem is that your header view will open some HTML tags which will be closed in footer view, such as `div#container`. That will make your code illegible.

My suggestion is:

```
$main_data['a']=...
$main_data['b']=...
$main_data['c']=...
$this->general_view('myview',$main_data);

protected function general_view($main_view,$main_data)
{
  $data['main_data']=$main_data;
  $data['main_view']=$main_view;
  $this->load->view('general_view',$data);
}
```

inside general view:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    ....
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <?$this->load->view('header');?>
    <div id="container">
      <?$this->load->view($main_view,$main_data);?>
    </div>
    <?$this->load->view('footer',$data);?>
  </BODY>
<HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a templating library, Here is a good one : [Stencil](https://github.com/scotch-io/stencil), Or use : [this way](https://gist.github.com/ncerminara/6251524)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, just add a file inside views named masterpage.php, then use the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class='menu'>My Menu here</div>
<div class='content'>
<?php echo $content; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

then your views shoud be like

```
<?php
  ob_start();
?>
content

<?php
  $content= ob_get_contents(); 
  ob_end_clean(); 
  include("application/views/masterpage.php");
?>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend a abstractClass to get an hierarchy index:

AbstractClass:

```
class AbstractController extends CI_Controller
{  
     var $_template;

     function __construct()
     {
        parent::__construct();
     }

     function index()
     {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view($this->_template);
        $this->load->view('footer',$data);
     }
}
```

Home Controller:

```
class Home extends AbstractController
{
   function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_template = "home/home_view";
   }
}
```

When you access site.com/home you gonna override $this->_template and with path for home view, and call index() from abstract controller

*Good Lucky*